# Magento Configurable Product Color Swatch Selection Not Updating Price in IE9 or 10

Tags: javascript, magento, configurable-product

thanks in advance for looking into this. I have searched through this forum and others to find a solution and have been unsuccessful

My setup: 
 Magento 1.7.0.2 
 Prototype 1.7.1 
 Jquery 1.7.1  
 Gala Color Swatches extension 
 Magento HTML5 Boilerplate (customized)

The Issue: On the product view page when clicking a configurable product option color swatch (with a price increase) in Internet Explorer 9 or 10, the product’s price does not change, nor do the additional color swatches populate. This issue does not present itself in ANY other browser including the latest Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. When the product is added to the cart the correct price and options are shown having been selected on the previous page.

The strange part is that when I change the browser mode and standards to Internet Explorer 8 or 7, the price is updated correctly. In addition, when custom options are selected the price updates but configurable options swatches do NOT.

I am really stuck with this and appreciate any help the community can give.

Answer (score 0):

Have your developers program the functionality themselves, or if you really have to, use a different module. One of these two should solve your problems:
http://www.extensionsmall.com/magento-color-swatch.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/netismine-colorswitcher-8223.html